# Equivalent of the "NoSuchElement" exception for Python Requests library?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I see Selenium has a NoSuchElement exception that can be used in a try statement, but Requests only seems to have ConnectionError, HTTPError, Timeout and TooManyRedirects exceptions.  I've looked everywhere but Selenium seems to be the only thing that comes up.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just import the exception from Selenium?

Comment: Hey that's a good idea, I'm going to try it.